# 1064 error with CodeIgniter in ci_sessions table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
// Run the update query
$this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
$this->CI->db->update($this->sess_table_name, array('last_activity' => $this->userdata['last_activity'], 'user_data' => $custom_userdata));
```

I have a problem using sessions in CodeIgniter. I downloaded de las CI version and I have to modify many things to make it works, but, when I'm trying to login in my web, I have this problem, with *1064 error MySQL*:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET `last_activity` = 1430854831, `user_data` =
>   'a:8:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1
>
> UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1430854831, `user_data` =
>   'a:8:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"id_cliente\";s:1:\"2\";s:4:\"name\";s:14:\"Martín
>   Sosa\";s:8:\"lastName\";s:6:\"Plaz\";s:9:\"lastName2\";s:4:\"Loah\";s:15:\"numberExpedient\";s:5:\"00002\";s:5:\"email\";s:27:\"mart94@hotmail.com\";s:3:\"rol\";s:1:\"1\";}'
>   WHERE `session_id` = '6b4cceb3679bdc63a4534c6be0efd54f'
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 289

Comment: According your error `$this->sess_table_name` is empty make sure you provide table name in `update()` function

Comment: I've edit the Sessions.php file, and I add a value to sess_table_name, but, the message it's the same, I checked mmy config.php file but, the variables, are not there, it is the new version of CI, but in the CI previous version I have, the variables there are in config.php, I don't WTF with that. :(

Comment: OLD config.php
`
$config['sess_cookie_name']='ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] =7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']=FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']=TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']=TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']='ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']=FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']=FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']=300;
`

Comment: new config.php variables
new
`
$config['sess_driver']= 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name']= 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']=7200;
$config['sess_save_path']=NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip']=FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']=300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy']=FALSE;
`
PS: I don't know how to put my code with de StackOverflow tags :(

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the session table name

```
update TABLE_NAME set ...
```

Is `$this->sess_table_name` properly set?

Check your config file for:

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Also, check the manual:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: In the new version of CI (3.0) I don't have that variables in config file, there are in /system/libraries/Sessions.php, but, I don't know if have to change them.

Comment: In CI3, the default $config['sess_driver']='files'; and 
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL; Since you set sess_driver to 'database',  try updating sess_save_path to "ci_sessions";

Comment: I just found this link http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver This should solve your problem.

Comment: @MartinRafaelPérezLara did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Check your config file:

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
```

Hope this helping...