# Codeigniter 3.0 session table name is empty string, hence getting error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

this is a strange scenario, as per codeigniter documentation, we can save session data on files or on db, now using their configuration these are my setting on `config.php` file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions'; // cookie name
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; // table name
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

now session table is working on localserver without any problem, but when running on live server, it show this error

> UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1438164724, `user_data` = 'a:2:{s:6:\"data\";s:6:\"value\";s:9:\"data_1\";s:15:\"value_1\";}' WHERE `session_id` = 'a0b6651bab02fda101ee10c11dee9979'

we can clearly see the session table name is blank, now is there anyway to find out why it is as blank, since we are using same setting in local server as well as in live server

Comment: It means you not created the table on live server

Comment: @Abdulla hi there is table on live server, more over, i just tested $config['sess_save_path'] = ''; with this line as empty value, and same error is popping up, maybe some bug?

Comment: Check my answer `$config['sess_table_name']` only contain table name

Comment: @Abdulla actually i'm using ci 3.0, the code you gave is from 2.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Session library is loaded.

`$this->load->library('session');`

Creating table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Or table details not provided to Codeigniter.

[More About CI Session](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: is there anyway to log the query, or table name so i can see what is going on? and yes session library is autoloaded and i've table in live server also :)

Answer (score 0):

Here `session_table_name` is missing. So you can check the following things,
Please make sure your session library is loaded. Also check, is `$this->sess_table_name` properly set? please check again the config file in live server for

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Please check this link for details http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

You can also check this post [1064 error with CodeIgniter in ci_sessions table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061945/1064-error-with-codeigniter-in-ci-sessions-table) which is related with your issue.Hope you will get a solution.

Comment: i'm getting this error **Undefined property: CI_Loader::$sess_table_name** while when i'm using session flash data it is working fine, that means session library is loaded and working

Comment: Check out this post, it will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086348/how-i-can-set-a-session-in-codeigniter-3-database